# How does the return info of the XML documentation show?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, xml-documentation

I love the XML documentation feature, the `<summary>` always shows up, and recently I found out how to make the function argument info in `<param>` visible in Intellisense by setting an Output Path in the Build tab of the property page of a class project or in web.config for the Web project. But so far I have not seen any benefit of writing documentation in the `<returns>` tag. How do I make this visible in Intellisense?

Comment: Don't forget that XML documentation isn't *just* for Intellisense. See http://nodatime.org/api for example

Comment: May I take this as a hint that the <return> info is just not available within VS? Too bad, as this would be useful.

Comment: I didn't want to imply that; I'm still looking at it myself. I just wanted to point out that there's more to XML documentation than Intellisense. (But no, having experimented a bit I can't see any way of seeing it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `<returns>` tag won't be shown by IntelliSense.

It is only shown in the Object Explorer.
It is also exported to the XML documentation (via options in the Build tab), so it can be used by documentation generators.